# Amchart 3 draw horizontal line based on xaxis value

Tags: amcharts

Hello friends I'm new to Amchart I want to draw a horizontal line on the graph please check the attached screenshot.

On Y-axis line location is 100 and on the X-axis value is April to July.

can you help me short out this issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

should be like this:

```
//add the trendlines

var trend = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());

trend.dataFields.valueY = "value2";

trend.dataFields.valueX = "value";

trend.strokeWidth = 2

trend.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(0);

trend.strokeOpacity = 0.7;

trend.data = [  { "value": 1, "value2": 2 },  { "value": 12, "value2": 11 }];
```